# Memory-Mapped Files, protecting individual view from overriding

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-mapped-files

- is it possible to protect view (pMap, pMap2) data from override each other?
- Or i need to do it manually?

For example when i execute my code the file data will be all "1".

Source code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO systemInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&systemInfo);

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("temp", GENERIC_EXECUTE | GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    // error check
    HANDLE hMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, 0, systemInfo.dwAllocationGranularity*2, "awMapMemory");
    // error check

    LPVOID pMap = MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, systemInfo.dwAllocationGranularity);
    LPVOID pMap2 = MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, systemInfo.dwAllocationGranularity, systemInfo.dwAllocationGranularity);
    // error check

    __try
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < systemInfo.dwAllocationGranularity; i++)
            *((char*)pMap2 + i) = 2;
        for(int i = 0; i < systemInfo.dwAllocationGranularity + systemInfo.dwAllocationGranularity; i++)
            *((char*)pMap + i) = 1;

        FlushViewOfFile(pMap, 0);
    }
    __except (GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR ? EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH)
    {
        // error
    }

    UnmapViewOfFile(pMap);
    CloseHandle(hMap);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would they override each other?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The purpose of MapViewOfFIle is sharing memory between different processes. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to use this method to store alot of data structures (3d coord, color, type...). Lets say view adresses are pMap = 0 and pMap2 = 10, if i write 11 bytes to address pMap i will end up writing into pMap2 first possition. Or i miss understand the point of MapViewOfFile?

Comment: @Michael The purpose of `MapViewOfFile` is to map a particular region of a file object into a process' address space. It **can** be used for IPC, but it's certainly not restricted to that scenario.

Comment: @alviduxxx: yes probably you missunderstand the point of MapViewOfFile. The behaviour your small program exhibits is normal.

Comment: @IInspectable: your are right, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Modern CPUs have an MMU. This device converts an address seen by the program to an address seen by the hardware.

Example: The MMU can be programmed in a way that (char *)0x1000 actually accesses address 0x12345000 instead of 0x1000.

Using the MMU in this way is absolutely essential for the memory management of modern operating systems!

When you use MapViewOfFile in the way you do it then the MMU will be programmed in a way that both pMap and pMap2 are converted to the same hardware address. An example:

```
pMap = (char *)0x1000 -> Hardware address 0x12345000
pMap2 = (char *)0x2000 -> Also hardware address 0x12345000
```

This means that pMap and pMap2 actually point to the **same address** (here 0x12345000). Therefore the program must behave the same way as if pMap and pMap2 contained the same pointer.